Image is not getting displayed from the MongoDB in the React website
I have built a website like a blog post. The image is being uploaded to MongoDB and has not been displayed on the website. I have checked whether the image is rendered using Postman; the image has been displayed and all the data is displayed. but the image is not displayed on the website. But once I refresh everything is gone, once I add a single post, only then all the posts are getting shown.  Can I get some help on solving this problem?
mongodb.js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import multer from 'multer';
import path from "path";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { title } from "process";
import './dbtest.js';
import cors from "cors";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = 8000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MongoDb_Connection_string,{
ssl: true,
});

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    content:String,
    image:String
});

const Post = mongoose.model('posts',postSchema);

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,'uploads/');
    },
    filename:function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,Date.now()+path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
})

const upload = multer({storage:storage});
app.use('/uploads',express.static('uploads'));

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));

app.post('/posts',upload.single('image'),async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        console.log(req.file);
        const{title,content} = req.body;
        const image = req.file ? `uploads/${req.file.filename}` : null;


        const newPost = new Post({title,content,image});
        await newPost.save();
        res.status(201).send('Post created sucessfully');

        
    }catch(error){
        res.status(500).send('Error creating post');
        console.error('Error creating post:', error);
    }
});

app.get('/posts', async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const posts = await Post.find();
    res.status(200).json(posts.map(post=>({
        ...post._doc,
        image: post.image ? `http://localhost:8000/${post.image}` : null
    })));
    } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send('Error fetching posts');
    console.error('Error fetching posts:', error);
    }
});


app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`server is running on http://localhost:${port}`)
})












HomePage.js
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Showcntnt } from "./content";
import axios from 'axios'




export function HomePage({ post }) {

  const [postList, setPostList] = useState(post);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get("http://localhost:3000/posts")
      .then(response => setPostList(response.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, []);
  
  
  
  
  
  
    return (
    <div>
        <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold text-center text-white mb-8">Welcome to Our Content Hub</h1>
        
        {/* Featured Section */}
        <div className="mb-12">
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-white mb-4">Featured Content</h2>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
            <div className="relative overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg">
            <img src="/giphy.gif" alt="Featured 1" className="w-full h-48 object-cover" />
            <div className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 opacity-70">
                <h3 className="text-xl text-white font-bold">Featured Item 1</h3>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="relative overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg">
            <img src="/giphy2.gif" alt="Featured 2" className="w-full h-48 object-cover" />
            <div className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 opacity-70">
                <h3 className="text-xl text-white font-bold">Featured Item 2</h3>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="relative overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg">
            <img src="/giphy3.gif" alt="Featured 3" className="w-full h-48 object-cover" />
            <div className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 right-0 px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 opacity-70">
                <h3 className="text-xl text-white font-bold">Featured Item 3</h3>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        {/* User-generated Content */}
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-white mb-4">Latest Posts</h2>
        {post.length === 0 ? (
        <div className="text-center text-gray-400">
            <p>No content available yet. Start by creating some!</p>
            <Link to="/createcontent" className="mt-4 inline-block bg-green-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-green-600 transition duration-300">Create Content</Link>
        </div>
        ) : (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-6">
            {post.map((item, index) => (
            <Showcntnt
                key={index}
                id={index}
                photo={item.image || "/uploads/placeholder.jpg"}
                title={item.title}
                content={item.content}
            />
            ))}
        </div>
        )}
    </div>
    );
}


content.js



export function Showcntnt({ photo, title, content }) {
    return (
      <div className="bg-gray-800 rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-hidden transition duration-300 transform hover:scale-105">

        <img 
        src={photo.startsWith('http') ? photo : `http://localhost:8000/${photo}`} 
        alt={title} 
        className="w-full h-48 object-cover" 
      />  

        <div className="p-4">
          <h2 className="font-bold text-xl mb-2 text-white">{title}</h2>
          <p className="text-gray-400">{content.substring(0, 100)}...</p>
          <button className="mt-4 bg-green-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-green-600 transition duration-300">
            Read More
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

